# why does the canvas element appear in the production assembly of the react?

Tags: reactjs

The canvas element is rendered when js is loaded, although I don't use canvas in the project, why is that?

```
<canvas style="inset: 0px; pointer-events: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1000000000;" width="959" height="750"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have noticed that canvas element appearing without a reason.
Turned out the React Dev tools extension was the culprit responsible for that canvas element (at least in Firefox).

From Firefox React Dev tools source code:

```
const root = window.document.documentElement;
root.insertBefore(canvas, root.firstChild);
```